# Find most recent time from list compared to my current time C#

Tags: c#, time

I have a list of times:

```
1:00
3:00
5:00
```

I need to select the most recent one compared to my current time.

So say the current time is `2:50`, I need the code to select `1:00`.
If the current time was `3:30`, it would select `3:00`, etc.

How can I write a for loop to accomplish this with any given list of times and a current time?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You are most likely to receive help if you make an attempt, show your work, and show where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *query* `times` with a help of *Linq* `MinBy`, e.g. having

```
        TimeOnly[] times = {
            new TimeOnly(1, 0),
            new TimeOnly(3, 0),
            new TimeOnly(5, 0),
        };
```

and

```
        TimeOnly current = new TimeOnly(2, 50);
```

you can put

```
        using System.Linq;

        ...

        var mostRecent = times
            .Where(time => time <= current) // past time only
            .MinBy(time => current - time);
```

No Linq solution can be a `for` loop:

```
        TimeOnly mostRecent = TimeOnly.MinValue;

        foreach (TimeOnly time in times)
            if (time <= current && mostRecent < time)
                mostRecent = time;
```

**Edit:** If collection (`TimeOnly[] times`) is in fact *ordered* we can use *binary search* instead of scan (see *Eric J. comment*):

```
        // if times is List<> then the syntax should be
        // int index = times.BinarySearch(current);
        int index = Array.BinarySearch(times, current);

        TimeOnly mostRecent = index >= 0 ? times[index] : times[~index - 1];
```

Comment: What about Linq-less solution? Does OP need to compare DateTime values? Just curious.

Comment: The OP implies by example that his list is ordered. If that is in fact true, this solution will unnecessarily scan the entire list (non-issue with a tiny list, but not great for a large one).

Comment: Can a solution be implemented without using TimeOnly 's? I am comparing DateTimes

Comment: @UTrocket23: sure; if *date* part matters, just change `TimeOnly` into `DateTime`; if, however, you want to *ignore* the date part, use `.Time` property, e.g. `.Where(time => time.Time <= current.Time).MinBy(time => current.Time - time.Time);`